# Talend Open Studio 5.5 tMap shifting columns in output

Tags: talend

Input is an excel spreadsheet with 10 columns. -- salary.xls

```
 rows 6 is: PreviousWeek
 Row 7 is: Previous YTD
 Row 8 is: Current YTD
```

Input file is passed through a tMap component which has a join to a text file "EmployeeOrder.txt".

Final output of the mapper has 11 columns
Column 1 is EmployeeOrder from the joined file.
remaining 10 columns from input spreadsheet salary.xls

the problem is, the values from the tMap output are being shifted i.e Col 6 is written into Col 7 and Col 7 into Col 8.

I checked the mapping and it seems all correct.

I know this is a shot in the dark question, but wondering if anyone faced something like this with OpenStudio 5.5.

Moving the columns doesnt seem to help either.

Any thing else I can look at for Troubleshooting this issue?  Any ideas?

Comment: are all the columns present, just shifted by 1?  in other words, column 1 is blank, and column 12 has data from column 11?  or does thr shift occur at a certain column?  Also what happens when you make column 1-10 come from salary.xls and column 11 from employeorder.txt?

Comment: @ELaRoche thanks for your comment. the shift happens just for the columns 6,7 and 8.  the others seem ok. column 1 maybe blank. could that be causing the shift?

Comment: You can try "Is absolute Y Pos." in the ExcelOutput component tab, and also try writing to xlsx format 9make sure to check the box in component tab).     I can't say I fully understand the problem, you should post more info.  For example since the shifting stops at column 9 where does column 8 data appear?  and if column 1 is blank why even pull from EmployeeOrder?  I would try it and make sure all columns have values, then see if shifting still happens.  if not then that the issue and you can come up a with a work around

Comment: I'd try to push the output of tMap to a tLogRow, and check if the problem still appears : at least you would know if problem comes from tMap or tFileOutputExcel component.

Comment: Is the shift at the first row or after ? can you provide an example of your data ?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and suggestions. Outputting to tLogRow highlighted the issue and I could fix it. Was tough to tell directly in a spreadsheet with 57 columns.